# Why defining object method fails in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Why when I try to define object method:

```
export class Helper {
    function add(x: number, y: number): number {
        return x + y;
    }
}
```

I get following error:

```
Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.
```

I followed example from this site: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html
But when I remove `function` keyword it works, but that contradicts the official source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use function inside a class! Change to it:

```
export class Helper {
    add(x: number, y: number): number {
        return x + y;
    }
}
```

Typescript doesn't allow functions as members of a class. So, change it to a method!

As said by **mattjes**, you could make the method static too...

```
export class Helper {
    static add(x: number, y: number): number {
        return x + y;
    }
}

Helper.add(1,2)
```

Comment: if you want it static just put `static` in front of the method declaration

Comment: No I don't want static(class) method,I want non-static(object) method.